# Mysql error 1064 when data read from sdcard have apostrophe - Android,PHP,MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysql-error-1064

What is the problem with the code

if data read from my sdcard informat of **"some big or small string"** then its work fine and show ***"successfully Entered"*** but when its with apostrophe like **"some big or small string's"** then its not work and show ***"oops! Please try again!"*** from my song.php file.

This one is my song.php code

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $date_today = $_POST['date_today'];
        $data_name = $_POST['data_name'];
        $data_value = $_POST['data_value'];


            require_once('Connect.php');

                $sql = "INSERT INTO songs VALUES('$data_name','$data_value','$date_today')";
                if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                    echo 'successfully Entered';
                }else{
                    echo 'oops! Please try again!';
                }

            mysqli_close($con);
}else{
echo 'error';
}
```

Connect.php

```
<?php
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','root');
    define('PASS','');
    define('DB','dracula');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
?>
```

SongData class

```
class SongData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ContentResolver mr = getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor mc = mr.query(uri,null,null,null,null);
        if (mc!=null&&mc.moveToFirst()){
            int titleColumn = mc.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = mc.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artist = mc.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            do{
                long thisId = mc.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = mc.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = mc.getString(artist);
                String mp = "TITLE "+thisTitle+"\nARTIST "+thisArtist;
                song += "\n\n-------------------------\n"+mp;
            }while(mc.moveToNext());
            mc.close();
        }
        return song;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        register(date_today, device, s, "http://192.168.1.102/song.php");
    }
}
```

here is register method.

```
 private void register(String data_name, String data_value,String date_current,String url) {
        class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
            ConnectionClass cc = new ConnectionClass();

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

                data.put("data_name",params[0]);
                data.put("data_value", params[1]);
                data.put("date_today", params[2]);
                String result = cc.sendPostRequest(params[3],data);

                return  result;
            }
        }

        RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
        ru.execute(data_name,data_value,date_current,url);
    }
```

Here is ConnectionClass.java

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class ConnectionClass {

    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                response = br.readLine();
            }
            else {
                response="Error Registering";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "not connected";
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        Log.i("result",result.toString());
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use mysqli_error() to find out what is happend.

Comment: its show <br/> only

Comment: see my song,php code, i out 'echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";'  in else.  @Jens

Comment: Mysqli_ not MySQL_

Comment: error is   **1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 't Back Down**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer. i edit and put below line in my SongData Class `onPostExecute` mehod

```
String newStr = s.replace("\'", "");
register(date_today, device, newStr, "http://192.168.1.102/song.php");
```